# Get file size and file type of a remote pdf. Parallel Curl is not always successful in getting this information

Tags: php, mysql, curl

I have approximately 2500 links of remote PDFs in my mysql database.
I have set up code to fetch these links and use multiple curl(parallel curl LIBRARY) to connect and fetch file size and file type.
Basically I want to check if a file is deleted/modified at the server.
So, in the database, when I saved all the links, I saved the size(in bytes) and type of the file at that time.

I have a cron setup to fetch all these links from the db and get the file size and type dynamically.
Here is my code:

```
$link_details = array();
    $max_requests = 400;
        $curl_options = array(
            CURLOPT_NOBODY => 1,
            CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 3,
            CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS => 20000
        );

        $parallel_curl = new ParallelCurl($max_requests, $curl_options);
        foreach ($unique_links as $link) 
        {
            $parallel_curl->startRequest($link, 'on_request_done', '');
        }
        $parallel_curl->finishAllRequests();

    function on_request_done($content, $url, $ch, $search)
        {
            global $link_details;
            $data = array();
            $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);   

            $content_type = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE); 
            $content_length = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD); 
            //echo "$url--$httpcode--$content_type--$content_length<br>";

            /*$sql_query = " SELECT 1 ";
            mysql_query($sql_query);*/

            curl_close($ch);

            if (($httpcode != 200 && $httpcode >= 400) || (empty($content_length) && empty($content_type))) 
            {
                $link_details[$url]['file_size'] = get_remote_file_size($url);
                $link_details[$url]['content_type'] = get_remote_header_info('content_type', $url);
                /*$link_details[$url]['file_size'] = 0;
                $link_details[$url]['content_type'] = '';*/
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                $link_details[$url]['file_size'] = $content_length;
                $link_details[$url]['content_type'] = $content_type;
                return;
            }
        }


    function get_remote_file_size($url)
    {
        ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); //no limit
        stream_context_set_default(array('http' => array('method' => 'GET')));
        $value = strlen(@file_get_contents($url));
        /*if(!$value)
        {
            $value = NULL;
        }*/
        return $value;
    }


    function get_remote_header_info($get, $url)
    {
        ini_set('max_execution_time', 5); //no limit
        stream_context_set_default(array('http' => array('method' => 'HEAD')));
        $head = @array_change_key_case(@get_headers($url, 1));
        $value = '';

        if(empty($head))
        {
            return NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            if($get == 'file_size')
            {
                $value = isset($head['content-length']) ? $head['content-length'] : NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                $value = isset($head['content-type']) ? $head['content-type'] : NULL;
            }
            return $value;
        }
    }
```

`$link_details` is actually an array which has the URLs as array keys. 
I try to use the functions `get_remote_file_size()` and `get_remote_header_info()` to get the size and type if CURL is unsuccessful in retrieving it.

FYI, on_request_done() function gets called each time a CURL request is done.
Sometimes, CURL is successful in getting these info, but sometimes, it is not.

I have also found out that in case of 302 redirections, CURL seems to be unsuccessful even though i have set `FOLLOW_LOCATION` to true. Please help.

Comment: the code might be correct but the server might refuse your request(too high load, rate limit, etc). Setting the user agent and referrer (imitating a real browser) can help sometimes

Comment: Okay, I guess, I can set the agent via the following code: CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)";   But, how can I add a referer?

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.google.com');

Comment: Didn't work. I am not sure if it is due to the issue with remote server. A URL is [link]http://dcra.dc.gov/sites/default/files/dc/sites/dcra/publication/attachments/Restated%20Articles%20of%20Incorporation%20of%20DBC%20DBU-3.pdf      A few minutes earlier, CURL could get the size and type of this remote pdf. Now, it cannot.

Comment: tested with REST client and could not get a good response(it is a html response) - so i'm guessing the is an error on the remote site

Comment: Okay, how can I use REST client to test a URL? Is it something publicly available. Using CURL, I get the size and type sometimes only. So I guess its something wrong with the server.

Comment: I use Advanced REST client which is a Chrome addon - but I'm pretty sure there are alternatives in other browsers - and you have to make a HEAD request and check the response headers

Comment: Thank You Sir, I checked with Advanced Rest Client. Now, it shows 200 as HTTP status and CURL can get the information. Can you please check now? The behaviour is strange.

Comment: It's HTTP 200 but there was a redirect to https://dcra.dc.gov/. So im guessing the file is deleted.

Comment: No Sir, the file is present in the server. CURL could get the details of the file. I have tried Advanced Rest Client and the response headers give content-type as application/pdf and a value for content-length. Not sure why this information is not always available.